# Installing Bit Bake Append'ed Packages with DNF cleanly

Tags: yocto, bitbake

It is common practice to customize a Yocto made package with an Bit Bake append file `_%.bbappend`. The problem I am having is even though the package contents have been modified due to the append file, the package keeps the same version number. This is troublesome because `dnf install` will not install the RPM because it does not think it is an upgrade and a `dnf remove` before would trigger dependent packages to also be removed. There are ways around this modifying DNF configs, but I get nervous automating those changes in utilities due to the chance of really nasty error states.

Assuming the original package is installed, is there any way to modify the Bit Bake append file so that `dnf` will install the result like an updated package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this is to use the PR service:

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#working-with-a-pr-service

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to set (and increment as you update) the PR variable as follows:

PR = "r1"

See: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-PR